# Gantry Framework: In particle, how to use Easyblog content provider?

Tags: gantry

Particles are very flexible and user-friendly, but they can only get Joomla's article as content provider, as http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/advanced/content-in-particles points out:

```
{% set options = {published: true, id: [14, 3]} %}
{% set finder = joomla.finder('category', options) %}
```

But very often people are using other components as main content organizer, such as K2 or Easyblog, especially when Easyblog allow users to directly create/edit articles from MS Word. It is not hard for me to retrieve Easyblog's posts in PHP:

```
<?php
// Include the engine
include_once(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_easyblog/includes/easyblog.php');

// Only fetch 10 posts
$limit = 10;

// Category id's (one or more)
$options = array(1);

$model = EB::model('Category');
$posts = $model->getPosts($options, $limit);
```

But gantry particles are using twig, which I am not very familiar with. So the question is, how do I integrate what I retireve from Easyblog via PHP into Gantry's twig environment?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for pulling content in particles is at: http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/advanced/content-in-particles

The short answer is that it is not easy and you might want to hire a developer to code that.  I would suggest asking if anyone would be willing to do it as a freelance project through the Gantry5 Gitter board. https://gitter.im/gantry/gantry5

I saw you already commented on the GitHub issue about this: https://github.com/gantry/gantry5/issues/1480

Comment: I'd like to learn how to develop this feature, just don't know where to start.